# Django Form issue

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using Django to  select language. One option works fine, but the other won't work

Option (1)  Works fine .

```
                      <select name="language" 

onchange="this.form.submit()" >
                            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %} >{{ lang.1 }} ({{ lang.0 }})</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
```

Option 1 : Not working using (form Submit Button )

```
                <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="LanForm" name="LanForm">
                    {% csrf_token %}                     
    <input class="lang" id="language" name="language" type="hidden" value="ar">
                     <input class="lang" id="setl" name="setl" type="submit" value="Go">
                    </form>
```

The select option works fine and change the language and redirect properly . But if I use the "Go" button , nothing is changing . I am wondering what is issue.

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide more details

Comment: Update the the question. using  A select option the language change  works fine . But if use the form with a button, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do not set more than one node with the same id.
Secondly, you have kept the name of both submit and hidden inputs same i.e, 'language'.

Use the below snippet and test again

```
 <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="LanForm" name="language">
    {% csrf_token %}                     
    <input class="lang" id="language" name="language" type="hidden" value="ar">
    <input class="lang" type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
```

Comment: I made the changes . But it sill won't work

Comment: what do LANGUAGES contain?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by modfing the form as follows,

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="LanForm" name="LanForm">
                        {% csrf_token %}   
                        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />                      
                       <input  name="language" type="hidden" value="ar" />
                        <input class="lang" name="language2" type="button" value="Go" onclick=" document.getElementById('LanForm').submit();" >
                    </form>
```

No ids no names in the input field